# Total war series with a dual monitor setup

Tags: hardware, shogun-2-total-war, rome-2-total-war

In the total war series, specifically Rome and Shogun Total war 2, you can scroll/rotate the map by moving the mouse cursor to the edge of the screen.

This works fine on a single monitor, but I have two monitors setup. When I move the mouse to the edge of the screen the game does not seem to detect this and as a consequence the map does not scroll/rotate.

Is there a way to remedy this, short of unplugging the second monitor?

Comment: I run into this problem with windowed games all the time.  Usually, I have to use the keyboard keys bound to map movement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try either of the following methods:

1. Use [Cursor Lock](http://www.snakebytestudios.com/projects/apps/cursor-lock/) to confine the mouse cursor to a selected area on the screen.
2. Press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> and choose *Projector/Computer only*, depending on whether your're playing on your secondary or main screen respectively. This will allow you to quickly switch between single or multiple monitors without unplugging the second monitor.

Comment: Perfect, option #2 was what I was looking for! (In case anyone else wants to use this, you have to alt-tab out of the game, then hit win+p, after whcih you can alt-tab to the game again).

Comment: Today, in 2020, Creative Assembly didn't fix this issue yet. :/